# Create Border around image when clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an assignment for school and have been trying to get the code to run as it is supposed to. At this point all I need is for the Onclick to work. I try to put a border around each thumbnail image that is clicked and then have the border removed once another image is clicked. I have looked at multiple resources, but can't seem to get this to work at all. If anyone can provide assistance it would be really appreciated. I am extremely new to JavaScript and am pretty lost with the resources I've been given. My resolution needs to be purely in JavaScript without any JQuery.

```js
// JavaScript Document //
var imgArray = new Array(
  //list of slides
  'chestnutp.jpg',
  'chestnuts.jpg',
  'elephant.jpg',
  'fall.jpg',
  'leaves.jpg'
);
var imgPath = "img/";

function swapImage(imgID) { //pulls image to larger area..
  var theImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  var newImg;
  newImg = imgArray[imgID];
  theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
  var element = document.getElementById("id20");
  element.innerHTML = "New Fall Photo Gallery"; //Additional change to DOM; changes original name
}
var captionArray = [
  //list of captions
  'A chestnut coming out of a plant on a fall day.',
  'A bundle of chestnuts on the ground on a fall day.',
  'An Elephant walking on an African Fall evening.',
  'A fall display with flowers and pumpkins.',
  'Looking up at the leaves on a fall day.'
];

function swapCaption(ID) { //creates caption when larger image is shown
  var theCaption = document.getElementById('caption');
  var newCaption;
  newCaption = captionArray[ID];
  theCaption.innerHTML = newCaption;
}

function mark(ID) { //creates border
  document.getElementById(ID).style.border = "2px solid orange";
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #322F2F;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#wrapper {
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#thumbnails {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

#thumbnails>img:hover {
  border: 1px #9D9C9C solid;
}

.thumbDown {
  border: none;
}

.thumbUp {
  border: 1px #9D9C9C solid;
}

.largeImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-size: .9em;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fall Air Photo Gallery</title>
  <!--Change title-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="js/image-gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 id="id20">Fall Air Photo Gallery</h1>
        <!--Change Header-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="thumbnails">
          <img src="img/chestnutp.jpg" id="chestnutp" onclick="mark(1)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Chestnut in Plant" onmouseover="swapImage(0); swapCaption(0)" />
          <!--onmouseover will switch images on hover-->
          <!--Onclick used to put border behind clicked imaged-->
          <img src="img/chestnuts.jpg" id="chestnuts" onclick="mark(2)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Chestnuts on the Ground" onmouseover="swapImage(1); swapCaption(1)" />
          <img src="img/elephant.jpg" id="elephant" onclick="mark(3)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Elephant walking the African fall sunset" onmouseover="swapImage(2); swapCaption(2)" />
          <img src="img/fall.jpg" id="fall" onclick="mark(4)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Fall display on a fall day" onmouseover="swapImage(3); swapCaption(3)" />
          <img src="img/leaves.jpg" id="leaves" onclick="mark(5)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Leaves on a Fall Day" onmouseover="swapImage(4); swapCaption(4)" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="mainImage">
          <img id="largeImage" src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="caption">
          <p id="caption"></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, your `JavaScript` is missing a closing bracket `}` at the very end.

Comment: This works as a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/0peetxpp/

Comment: Other then the closing bracket at the end. Your onclick trigger is not selecting any existing id. if you want to to fire the mark() function and use the id you must use each individual elements id on the onclick event like so onclick="mark('chestnutp')". the others to follow must have their unique id instead of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that your `mark()` function is passing hard-coded numbers, but there are no elements that have the `id` property set with a number. Note that your `<img>` id properties are strings.

What you could do for those instead, is to set each mark call to pass the element id, like so:

```
onclick="mark(this.id)"
```

With that minor change, you will see that your borders turn orange. However, there will still be the matter of clearing the other borders...

To clear the borders, you can loop the children of the parent element to remove all borders before setting the one that was clicked. You could do this inside the `mark` function, or some other function/handling, but I'll change the `mark` function for this example:

```
function mark(ID) { //creates border
    var childImages = document.getElementById("thumbnails").children;
    var i;

    // clear any other borders that might be set
    for ( i = 0; i < childImages.length; i++ ) {
       childImages[i].style.border = '';
    }

    // Then set the one that got clicked.
    document.getElementById(ID).style.border="2px solid orange";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(document).on("click","#thumbnails img",function(){
 $(this).css("border","5px solid orange");
 $("#thumbnails img").not($(this)).css("border","none");
});
});
```

```css
#thumbnails > img{
 border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnails">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
</div>
```

Comment: He said the project is to be done in vanilla javascript only, no libraries. Although this is a nicer cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your images a class name like class="img" then push them into an array using getElementsByClassName(). Also remember to start your mark(i) i value from 0 when filling in the onclicks.

```
<script>
var array = document.getElementsByClassName("img"); //pushes all your img 
function mark(i,j)                                  //divs into an array
{
    array[i].style.border = "2px solid orange"; //makes the border on click
    for(j = 0; j < array.length ; j++) //this for loop will remove the 
     {                                // border of every other img div
        if(j != i)
        {
            array[j].style.border="none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick trigger is not selecting any existing id. It is instead searching for an element with the number you entered as an id.

**Your current onclick event:**

```
onclick="mark(1)"
```

Is searching for an element with an id equal to one (ex: id="1")

It should instead be triggering the mark() function using "this" to tell javascript to run the function on the current element.

**your onclick events should be changed to:**

```
onclick="mark(this)"
```

**And update your mark() function to:**

```
function mark(currentEl) {
    // Retreives the id of current element that is clicked
    var id = currentEl.id;

    // Apply the border 
    document.getElementById(id).style.border="2px solid orange";
}
```

Once you apply this change a border will appear, however, it will wont go away once clicked on another image. I am assuming you would like the border to appear on current image clicked only to highlight the active image and be removed from the previous.

**Alternate function to only highlight the active image:**
I am using a conditional here for an easier understanding. @Paul T's approach is a great alternative if you are familiar with for loops.

```
// set an empty variable to compare later
var previousEl;

function mark(currentEl) {

    // Retrieves the id of current element that is clicked
    var id = currentEl.id;

    /**
    * Checks to see if a previous element has been clicked
    * if it was, it will remove the border from the previous and apply it to the current element
    */
    if(previousEl){
        previousEl.style.border = "unset"; // css unset border
        currentEl.style.border = "2px solid orange"; // apply border to current element
        previousEl = document.getElementById(id); // assign current element id to previousEl variable 
    } else {
        currentEl.style.border = "2px solid orange";
        previousEl = document.getElementById(id);
    }
}
```

**Below is a working snippet using the alternate function.**

```js
// JavaScript Document
var imgArray = new Array(
    //list of slides
    '/400/200/abstract',
    '/400/200/abstract',
    '/400/200/abstract',
    '/400/200/abstract',
    '/400/200/abstract'
);
var imgPath = "http://lorempixel.com";

function swapImage(imgID) { //pulls image to larger area..
    var theImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    var newImg;
    newImg = imgArray[imgID];
    theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
    var element = document.getElementById("id20");
    element.innerHTML = "New Fall Photo Gallery"; //Additional change to DOM; changes original name
}
var captionArray = [
    //list of captions
    'A chestnut coming out of a plant on a fall day.',
    'A bundle of chestnuts on the ground on a fall day.',
    'An Elephant walking on an African Fall evening.',
    'A fall display with flowers and pumpkins.',
    'Looking up at the leaves on a fall day.'
];

function swapCaption(ID) { //creates caption when larger image is shown
    var theCaption = document.getElementById('caption');
    var newCaption;
    newCaption = captionArray[ID];
    theCaption.innerHTML = newCaption;
}

// set an empty variable to compare later
var previousEl;

function mark(currentEl) {
    
    // Retreives the id of current element that is clicked
    var id = currentEl.id;
    
    /**
    * Checks to see if a previous element has been clicked
    * if it was, it will remove the border from the previous and apply it to the current element
    */
    if(previousEl){
        previousEl.style.border = "unset"; // css unset border
        currentEl.style.border = "2px solid orange"; // apply border to current element
        previousEl = document.getElementById(id); // assign current element id to previousEl variable
    } else {
        currentEl.style.border = "2px solid orange"; // 
        previousEl = document.getElementById(id);
    }
}
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #322F2F;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#thumbnails {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

#thumbnails>img:hover {
    border: 1px #9D9C9C solid;
}

.thumbDown {
    border: none;
}

.thumbUp {
    border: 1px #9D9C9C solid;
}

.largeImage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.caption {
    font-size: .9em;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fall Air Photo Gallery</title>
    <!--Change title-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/image-gallery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 id="id20">Fall Air Photo Gallery</h1>
                <!--Change Header-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="thumbnails">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" id="chestnutp" onclick="mark(this)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Chestnut in Plant" onmouseover="swapImage(0); swapCaption(0)" />
                    <!--onmouseover will switch images on hover-->
                    <!--Onclick used to put border behind clicked imaged-->
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" id="chestnuts" onclick="mark(this)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Chestnuts on the Ground" onmouseover="swapImage(1); swapCaption(1)" />
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" id="elephant" onclick="mark(this)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Elephant walking the African fall sunset" onmouseover="swapImage(2); swapCaption(2)" />
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" id="fall" onclick="mark(this)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Fall display on a fall day" onmouseover="swapImage(3); swapCaption(3)" />
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" id="leaves" onclick="mark(this)" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="Leaves on a Fall Day" onmouseover="swapImage(4); swapCaption(4)" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="mainImage">
                    <img id="largeImage" src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p id="caption"></p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addBorder(id) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
   x.item(i).style.border = 'none';
  }
  id.style.border = '5px solid orange';
}
```

```html
<img class="img" onclick="addBorder(this)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
<img class="img" onclick="addBorder(this)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
<img class="img" onclick="addBorder(this)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMZPrNzLxySwT9GuHbz33ZyNXFJtBrqg_ruleaepzXq2zf3NOewA"/>
```